# Small HTML Table issue

Tags: css, html, html-table

I have the above table shown in this picture. I want to fix the space between the Jill and Smith. Take the last table as an example. Not sure how to explain this because English is not my native language.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC4CP.png

**EDIT**

My code

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Jill</td>
      <th>Smith</td> 
      <th>Santa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith5555</td> 
      <td>50555555555</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jillffff</td>
      <td>Smith5555</td> 
      <td>50555555555</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill5555</td>
      <td>Smith5555</td> 
      <td>50555555555</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**CSS**

```
table, th, td {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    padding:10px;
}
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
table td {
    font-size:13px;
}
table th {
    text-align:left;
    font-size:14px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:normal;
    background:#36c;
    color:#fff;
}
tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Comment: Show some code, we can't help if we can't see what you've done :)

Comment: @ProgrammingNewb Added

Comment: what about your css file?

Comment: My guess is this has something to do with the css so if you show the style you have on the table that would help

Comment: @ProgrammingNewb Added CSS too

Comment: I don't see any reason for the first column to be so markedly different than the other columns. Are you sure there isn't some other styling being applied from somewhere? Or is there a very wide value in that column which you didn't include in your picture?

Comment: I think I found it^^, it was in your CSS file, if you remove the width and maybe the padding. your table should be just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where your problem is,

```
 table, th, td {
    width:100%; //This makes your table too big
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    padding:10px;
}
```

I'd say remove the width attribute and your table should be fine :)

It was your CSS code

Comment: @SantaClaus he copied off my answer, haha

Comment: I did look at the question fully, for the record. He made the CSS update to the question while I was still typing out my answer. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `width` in your `CSS` as mentioned in the code below.

> To improve your HTML, `<th>` elements have been closed as `</td>`. Please change it to `</th>`.

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;  /* Make table 100% */
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th {
  width: 33.33%;  /* Make column i.e <th> 33.33% */
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
  background: #36c;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the notice, didn't even saw that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the width attribute. Currently, you have it set to 100%. That means it's going to take up the entire width of the screen. Perhaps, this

```
<style>table, th, td {
        width:auto; //auto will adjust the table width automatically based on the size of each column
        border:1px solid #ddd;
        padding:10px;
         }
    table {
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    table td {
        font-size:13px;
    }
    table th {
        text-align:left;
        font-size:14px;
        text-transform:uppercase;
        font-weight:normal;
        background:#36c;
        color:#fff;
    }
    tr:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

You will want to add `width` <del>attribute</del> (this is depreciated in HTML5, forgot) style to your `<th>` tags.

For example

```
<tr>
  <th style="width:35%">Jill</td>
  <th style="width:35%">Smith</td> 
  <th style="width:30%">Santa</td>
</tr>
```

In addition you should not have `100%` width for `th` or `td`. Change your CSS to:

```
table {
    width:100%;
}
table, th, td {
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Comment: Is there any way without the width to every `th` tags? Maybe in CSS?

Comment: I'm torn: I dearly want to downvote for the suggestion of adding widths to Every. Single. Header. Cell. On the other hand, giving only the table (***not*** its cells) a 100% width might actually solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!